# logo is not coming for large screen in Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-screen-support

Here i am not creating different layout files for different screen. 
I want to display same logo and icons for every screens, for the large Screen it is not coming and for the normal screen in the Action bar, it displaying like very well. Please suggest me whats wrong with this. 
What code i need to change ? Thanks a ton.

Customized Action bar:

```
 <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/product_category_logo</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_theme</item>
<item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/black</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
Updated:

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: where i have to put this??

Comment: @user3154663 Into your menu xml file where you have your icon

Comment: my icon is not coming  not the menu. @nitesh

Comment: @user3154663 Have you customised your action Bar ? Post some code ...for Reference

Comment: but for the small screen its working fine only for large its not working @nitesh

Comment: @user3154663 what is Your minimum sdk and targetsdk

Comment: 16 minimum And targeted 19 Still not working @nitesh